# How to use Mongoose to find and update one of N embedded documents contained in an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose to update a field in an embedded document contained within in an array

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const projectActivitySchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
    }
});

const projectSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    label: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    activities: {
        type: [projectActivitySchema]
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

const Project = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);

export default Project;
```

I have ids for the project and activity and a new values for my label
Say I want to change the label for one of my activities...

I tried this:

```
        Project.findOne(filter).then(doc=> {
          let activities = doc.activities;

          activity = activities.find(idMatch);
          activity.label = label;

          doc.save();
```

I end up getting no results back. No feedback. Nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to use the mongoose `Model.findOneAndUpdate` method. You can search inside the `Project` and inside the `activities` array to look for match. Once found you can use the `$` positional operator to update only the array element that made the match from the `activities` array like so:

```js
Project.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        id: projectId,
        "activities.id": activityId
    },
    {
        $set: {
           "activities.$.label": 'New Value Here'  
        }
    },
    {new: true}
).then(doc => {
   console.log(doc);
   return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Project Updated'
   })
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error on server'
   })
});
```

Comment: Thank you jQueeny, trying to learn here and it just wasn't "gelling" for me. Are there any books or sites on Mongo and Mongoose you'd recommend? I'd like to git gud.

Comment: @YipYipYuppers you're welcome. To be honest, nothing compares to actually testing and building applications but MongoDB offers free training to support anyone looking to get MongoDB Certified. I would start [here](https://learn.mongodb.com/learning-paths/introduction-to-mongodb).